# How to turn a running Windows CMD in Admin?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I would like to know if it is possible to turn a Windows command into Administration mode after having started the command (and so by using the command).

So I start a normal session:

```
C:\Users\ME>
```

And FROM this latter session I want to obtain an administrative session, like this one:

```
C:\Windows\system32>
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/216230-how-change-admin-mode-cmd.html#post1812743

> CMD needs to be invoked with the required credentials to begin with,
>   as it is not possible to change this from within an existing CMD
>   window. By default, this is as a standard user (even from within an
>   administrative account). To open in elevated mode, see: Elevated
>   Command Prompt

So for all intents and purposes, what you're trying to do isn't possible under windows.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `runas`.

E.g. `runas /user:domainname\username cmd.exe`

The `/user:` shoudl have administrative permissions on the machine.

I'm not sure if there is a way to stay within the same console window (i.e. you'll notice the new `cmd.exe` will open in a new window) but I think this is related to the fact that windows can only be run under the particular user context so you can't elevate the running application.

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn a second cmd process that has administrator rights through PowerShell, as follows:

```
 powershell "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs"
```